# Two dimensional PDF candidate for barbell like distribution

Tags: distributions, density-function, bivariate

I have this empirical sample, which I drew on the scatter plot. It's got to be unimodal according to theory, and it surely does look like one. A simple way to model it is with bivariate normal. However, the marginals appear to be fat-tailed and slightly skewed, e.g. skewed t-distribution has a similar shape.

Can you suggest candidate distributions for this kind of data?

I fit the Gaussian kernel density estimator for a contour plot just for fun, I don't think this particular kernel would be a good fit because it can't produce fat tails.

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of your fitting?  What do you want to do with the fitted distribution?

Comment: I'm thinking about simulating the tails

Comment: And what is the purpose of simulating the tails?

Comment: If you just want to simulate the tails, and they are fat, you could model the tails by fitting a power law to them.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, to create stress scenarios.

Comment: A bivariate Log-normal perhaps, perform a log transform on the data and see if it looks very much like a bivariate normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sort of looks somewhere between

1. a bivariate $t$ (correlated normals divided by the square root of the same chi-squared variate, and then scaled and/or shifted as needed)
2. correlated normals divided by the square root of the independent chi-squared variates, and then scaled and/or shifted as needed

[image]

```
 # code:
 x=rnorm(100000)
 y=.8*x+.6*rnorm(100000)
 z=sqrt(rchisq(100000,8)/8)
 z2=sqrt(rchisq(100000,8)/8)
 plot(-x/z,y/z,pch=16,cex=0.1,col=4)
 plot(-x/z,y/z2,pch=16,cex=0.1,col=4)
```

as such it's possible that you *might* get a reasonable approximation by dividing correlated normals by the square root of somewhat correlated chi-squared variates, perhaps something like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
z=rchisq(10000,3)
z1=sqrt((rchisq(10000,5)+z)/8)
z2=sqrt((rchisq(10000,5)+z)/8)
plot(-x/z1,y/z2,pch=16,cex=0.1,col=4)

z=rchisq(10000,6)
z1=sqrt((rchisq(10000,2)+z)/8)
z2=sqrt((rchisq(10000,2)+z)/8)
plot(-x/z1,y/z2,pch=16,cex=0.1,col=4)
```

Comment: This is interesting